# Choose NotificationTone

Tags: android, notifications, ringtone, android-audiomanager

How can i use this

```
Ringtone tone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, Uri.parse(uri));
```

to choose from Notification Sound? 
This works fine, but i can set a notification sount from phone Ringtones.

Update:

```
private void update_notifytone (String uri, boolean save) {
        mNotifyTone = uri;
        if (uri == null) return;

        Ringtone tone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, Uri.parse(uri));


        if (tone != null) 
            mPrefNotifyTone.setSummary(tone.getTitle(this));
        if (save) 
            update_column(ProfileModel.ProfileColumns.NOTIFYTONE, mNotifyTone);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 RingtoneManager mRing= new RingtoneManager(RingtoneActivity.this); 
 int mNumberOfRingtones = mRing.getCursor().getCount();

 Uri mRingToneUri = mRing.getRingtoneUri((int) (Math.random() * mNumberOfRingtones));
```

the cursor provided by RingtoneManager to have access to the available ringtones on the device, in the example choosing a random one.

Comment: Thanks for response, but still i cannot acces the Notification Sounds.

Comment: welcome - with mRing.getCursor() you should get a cursor which you can use to access the sounds - where does it go wrong?

Comment: Please see my Updated Question with code. I want to do your answer in my method

Comment: It's ok :). Hmm..I still cannot see where is the issue, because this work just fine, but instead of Ringtones i want Notification Tones